# Validate Input in C array and check value of char

Tags: c

I'm trying to get user input of a string in format XXXXXXXXB where X is a digit and B is a char. I then want to validate the input is the correct format and check the Char to see if is A,B,C,D so i can out put the correct thing

problem i am having is how do i check the value of the char??
this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void validate(char array[]){
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    if(isdigit(array[i])){
    printf("Valid int %d at %d\n",array[i],i);
    }

    else if(isalpha(array[i])){
    printf("Valid alpha %c at %d\n",array[i],i);

        switch(isalpha(array[9])){
        case 'a':
            printf("Char a");
            break;
        case 'b':
            printf("Char b");
            break;
        case 'c':
            printf("Char c");
            break;
        case 'd':
            printf("Char d");
            break;
        }
    }

}
}

  int main(void) {
printf("Please Enter a string in format xxxxxxxxb x=digit b=char\n");
fflush(stdout);
char input[9];

gets(input);
validate(input);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right up front. remember C arrays are zero-based. I.e. valid indexing of an N-sized array is `[0..(N-1)]`. You're assuming your input is `char[9]` compatible (8 digits + 1 special char), so your digit check should be from `[0..7]` and your special char should be `[8]`.

Comment: also the isalpha check in the switch statement should not be there.

Comment: and the `fflush()` on stdout is redundant; it was flushed with the newline in your printf call. and don't use `gets()`, it is such an evil function it has ben deprecated from the standard library. use `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider two things-

1) **Check for proper index** - `array[9]` is the value at `10th index` of an array

2) **Check for case sensitive** - `b` is not same as `B`. So you might want to either compare using `ascii` values or covert the input char into lower case before comparing in `switch`

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the right spot in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void validate(char array[]){
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
if(isdigit(array[i])){
printf("Valid int %d at %d\n",array[i],i);
}

else if(isalpha(array[8])){
printf("Valid alpha %c at %d\n",array[i],i);

    switch(isalpha(array[9])){
    case 'a':
        printf("Char a");
        break;
    case 'b':
        printf("Char b");
        break;
    case 'c':
        printf("Char c");
        break;
    case 'd':
        printf("Char d");
        break;
    }
}

}
}

int main(void) {
printf("Please Enter a string in format xxxxxxxxb x=digit b=char\n");
fflush(stdout);
char input[9];

gets(input);
validate(input);

return 0; 
}
```